# Rows reappearing in Tables after Auto-Vacuum Failure in PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, duplicates, delete-row, antivirus

Version: PostgreSQL 10.21, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Platform: Windows

In our application code, we've implemented logic to clean up entries in several PostgreSQL tables using a loop. Although some of these tables have foreign key references, we've included them to ensure a thorough deletion process. Here's a simplified code snippet:

```
String tables[] = {"TableA", "TableB", "TableC", "TableD", "TableE", "TableF", "TableG", "TableH"};

for (String tableName : tables) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
        stmt.execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log the exception
    }
}
```

Notably, it leaves entries in different tables each time, and we've found auto-vacuum failure traces in the pg_log for these tables at the same time. Here's an example of the error messages from pg_log:

`2023-09-28 12:03:35.955 IST,,,11592,,65151e2d.2d48,1,,2023-09-28 12:03:17 IST,6/19,122786262,ERROR,42501,"could not truncate file ""base/16509/6935026"" to 0 blocks: Permission denied",,,,,"automatic vacuum of table ""DB.public.TableB""",,,,"" 2023-09-28 12:03:37.205 IST,,,11592,,65151e2d.2d48,2,,2023-09-28 12:03:17 IST,6/45,122786326,ERROR,42501,"could not truncate file ""base/16509/6935443"" to 0 blocks: Permission denied",,,,,"automatic vacuum of table ""DB.public.TableB""",,,,""`

We've already attempted to exclude the entire pg folder from antivirus scans, but the problem persists. Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like an issue with file permissions, not something within PostgreSQL. You could have avoided the need for vacuum by using `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`. You are aware that version 10.21 is EOL?

Comment: `autovacuum` runs as the user the 'owns' the cluster as it was initially setup. Looks someone changed the file permissions in `base/16509/*` and possibly higher up the directory path to a user other then the user Postgres used to `initdb` the cluster. Now `autovacuum` cannot work on the files.

Comment: If rows actually reappear after having been deleted, and the deleting transaction has committed,  that would be data corruption. The "permission denied" error also means that something is wrong (although it may be intermittent effects of a virus scanner, which you shouldn't allow in the data directory). You might be suffering from data corruption, which would match the fact that you are using outdated software. Consider hiring an expert. To delete all data from a table, use `TRUNCATE`.